# Querying MySQL with UNION and I'm getting an error on one of the columns I'm selecting

Tags: php, mysql, union

The query works just fine like:

```
$query = '(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM videos)
UNION
(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM games)
UNION
(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM pics)
ORDER BY date2 DESC
LIMIT 10';
$r = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

but WILL NOT work if I try to pull the column, **on**. All of the tables in the database use a column named **on**. I get this error: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on, type, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM videos) UNION (SELECT contentty' at line 1**

example of me adding **on** to me query:

```
$query = '(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, on, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM videos)
UNION
(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, on, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM games)
UNION
(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, on, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM pics)
ORDER BY date2 DESC
LIMIT 10';
$r = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Doesn't make sense to me. Why would this occur?

Answer (score 2):

Escape the `on` field as it's one of [MySQL's reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

```
$query = '(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, `on`, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM videos)
UNION
(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, `on`, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM games)
UNION
(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, `on`, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM pics)
ORDER BY date2 DESC
LIMIT 10';
```

Comment: You rock! Thanks. I actually used to have them all quoted that way. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

`ON` is [a reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Quoting it should work. I.e:

```
(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, `on`, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM videos)
UNION
(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, `on`, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM games)
UNION
(SELECT contenttype, id, title, type, `on`, image, rating, date2, num_votes FROM pics)
ORDER BY date2 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You rock! Thanks. I actually used to have them all quoted that way. Works great!